# Specifying data type and analyzer while creating index

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic search to index my data and i was able to do it with the following POST request
http://localhost:9200/index/type/id
{
  JSON data over here
}

Yesterday while i was going through some of the elastic tutorials i found one person mentioning about setting analyzer to those fields where we are planning to do full text search.I found during my googling that mapping API can be used to update datatypes and analyzer, but in my case i want to do it as i am creating index.

How can i do it?

Comment: You can specify analyzers in your settings when creating index.

Comment: Can i give the datatype with analyzer as well as data in same request? If so can you provide me a sample or a URL that has one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create index with custom settings (and mappings) in the first request and then index your data with second request. In this case you can not do both at the same time.

However if you index your data first and index does not exist yet, it will be created automatically with default settings. You can then update your mappings.

Source: [Index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html)

Comment: I was just thinking may that's the only possibility i can do to implement the above scenario. Thanks for clarifying Primoz.

Comment: So i create the index by mentioning the mapping and then insert the data right?

Comment: curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test -d '{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "type1" : {
            "properties" : {
                "field1" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
            }
        }
    }
}
From the above code we are creating an index test and type1 is the type and it has column field1 of datatype string and index as not_analyzed

How can i specify mappings based on type ?

Comment: Because from UI perspective, i will select a particular type , say customer and hit index button, i have to fetch data from another db ,create type if not exists and push data and before pushing i need to set analyzed for what all fields i have to do full text search

Comment: i guess i have found the answer. Give request body as {
  "properties": {
    "zip": {
      "type": "string",
       "index" : "not_analyzed" 
    }
  }
}

with PUT method and URL as http://localhost:9200/indexName/_mapping/typeName . Anything wrong , please correct me